# problem in Group policy

Tags: windows

We have a problem with all machines in our network: we cannot enable firewall in any machines including servers. When we try we see the following message:

> Windows server can't change some of your settings because they are controlled by Group Policy. Contact your system administrator if you need to change the settings

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I think you missed a copy/paste with the preformatted text?

Comment: This isn't really on-topic here as it is simply a Windows configuration issue. You need to alter your Group Policy as it looks like it is currently set up to disallow this.

Comment: Find the Gruup Policy that's being used to configure the firewall and then configure it accordingly. If you're not sure how to do that then post back here for instructions (I'll give you a hint, you can use gpresults or rsop).

Answer (score 0):

Are your machine joined to a domain? If so, then you can use the Group Policy Editor and modify the Firewall policies.

Answer (score 0):

Group policies are normally pushed from the Active Directory server. On that server, run `gpmc.msc` (as a domain admin) to see and edit Group Policy Objects. A GPO is applied on an *organizational unit* in the AD tree, and thus impacts all servers whose "computer account" is in that OU or a sub-OU thereof. Moving the computer account itself in the tree thus changes which GPO apply to that machine.